# How can I update a password in WordPress via PHP when I have a new MD5 password hash and not a cleartext password?

Tags: php, wordpress, md5, change-password

I have to process password changes from a remote system in WordPress where the external system calls an endpoint made available by our WP plugin and only provides the UserID and MD5 hashed password, not the cleartext password. I need to replace the password hash for that user in WP with the updated hash to maintain sync across the two platforms.

All of the current WP functions appear to accept only a cleartext password that they hash on the way into the database, for example:

```
wp_set_password( string $password, int $user_id )
```

I've tried setting the password via SQL in the plugin, but that's not working and I'm not sure why.

```
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->query( "UPDATE $wpdb->users SET user_pass = '$user_pass', user_activation_key = '' WHERE user_login = '$user_login'" );
```

Where, in the above SQL, `$user_pass` contains the password hash received from the external system, and not a cleartext password.

Is there a clean way of accomplishing this that I'm missing, or something about the SQL syntax above that's incorrect?

**Update:**

I can populate the user_pass field in the database for the user with the provided MD5 hash, and can leverage the WP mechanism where it will update to PHPass on the users next login, but I’m running into some really strange behavior whereby *this only works with very limited passwords and their resulting MD5 hash*.

If the hashed password is 16 characters and all upper case, setting the hash into the database allows the user to login, and the password is updated to PHPass in the database. Similarly if the password is ‘wordpress’, the generated hash can be loaded into the database, and the user can login. If the password is anything else, it fails, either the login screen refreshes with no warning, or a ‘invalid login’ error is displayed.

This makes no sense to me. Is there some kind of limitation I’m tripping over here? A configuration option I can set to make this work as I expect it to? Is this a bug?

Comment: WordPress doesn't use just straight MD5 for passwords. Instead it uses 256 rounds of salt passwords, and stores it in ["portable format"](https://www.openwall.com/phpass/). If you just have a raw MD5 string, it won't work. However, you could probably just use `wp_set_password` to set the password to a hash of the existing hash, and then override [`wp_check_password`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_check_password/) and add an MD5 round in there.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I've found that if I generate an MD5 hash of a password that's 16 characters and all upper-case, add that hash to the WordPress database directly, then I can login via the WP login form, and the password gets updated to PHPass format for future logins. If I generate an MD5 hash for a password that's longer, all lower case (other than, strangely 'wordpress'), contains numbers or special characters, that doesn't work at all. Any idea what may be the limiting factor there?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I don't know that. I do know that the core `wp_check_password` function looks for password hashes that are 32 characters or less and assumes that they are legacy MD5 passwords and "upgrades" them. But I don't really know why casing or characters would matter. Is it possible that whatever is generating the hashes from the other system has a bug? The code for this is [very basic](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_check_password/#source), and I can't think of anything that would cause what you are seeing on the WordPress side of things.

Comment: Thanks - I'm using an online MD5 hash generator, and have confirmed the hash with a second one for testing in case the remote system is doing something funky with their hash generation scheme. It doesn't make any sense to me at all, unless the short or all caps passwords make short hashes, and the others generate longer than 32 character hashes - that's something I can confirm at least.